# Having troubles with synchronous rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

```
const Temp = () => {
  const [temp, setTemp] = useState("Not Changed");
  const SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:8000";
  const token = Cookies.get("token");
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Jwt ${token}`,
    },
  };
  Axios.get(`${SERVER_URL}/accounts/4`, config)
    .then((res) => {
      setTemp(res.data.data.first_name);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  return <h1>HI I'm {temp}!!</h1>;
};

export default Temp;
```

When I execute the code, the screen initially shows "Hi I'm Not Changed" and shortly after changes to "Hi I'm John" with John being the first name of the user with the id number of 4.

In this case, what can I do to make the return code wait until it gets the first name of the user and just show "Hi I'm John", instead of presenting "Hi I'm Not Changed" before getting the response from the back servers and changing the value of temp?

Comment: Have some flag you can set when fetching is done and render your 'Hi (...)' part based on that flag: `[isFetchFinished, setIsFetchFinished] = useState(false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag to notify you once the promise fulfills.

If not, return a null value to the DOM.

```
const Temp = () => {
  const [temp, setTemp] = useState("Not Changed");
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:8000";
  const token = Cookies.get("token");
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Jwt ${token}`,
    },
  };
  Axios.get(`${SERVER_URL}/accounts/4`, config)
    .then((res) => {
      setTemp(res.data.data.first_name);
      // set flag to true once the val you want is received
      setIsLoaded(true);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  // display only once temp is set with val from server
  if (isLoaded) { 
    return <h1>HI I'm {temp}!!</h1>;
  }
  // return null to display empty 
  return null;
};
```

Comment: happy to help :)